# Using Jhipster with Prometheus/Grafana

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to figure out how to run and view prometheus and graphana dashboards with JHipster...

I enabled prometheus in my spring boot prod.yml

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
```

started the whole stack with:

`docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up`  (it starts up good)

and then tried

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/monitoring.yml up
```

but get:

> ERROR: for docker_y-prometheus_1  Cannot start service y-prometheus:
>   Mounts denied:  The path
>   /Developer/dev/jhipster/y/src/main/docker/prometheus is not shared
>   from OS X and is not known to Docker. You can configure shared paths
>   from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing. Creating
>   docker_y-grafana_1    ... error .
>
> ERROR: for docker_y-grafana_1  Cannot start service y-grafana: Mounts
>   denied:  The path
>   /Developer/dev/jhipster/y/src/main/docker/grafana/provisioning is not
>   shared from OS X and is not known to Docker. You can configure shared
>   paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing. See
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info. .
>
> ERROR: for y-grafana  Cannot start service y-grafana: Mounts denied: 
>   The path
>   /Developer/dev/jhipster/y/src/main/docker/grafana/provisioning is not
>   shared from OS X and is not known to Docker. You can configure shared
>   paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing. See
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info. .
>
> ERROR: for y-prometheus  Cannot start service y-prometheus: Mounts
>   denied:  The path /Developer/dev/jhipster/y/src/main/docker/prometheus
>   is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker. You can configure
>   shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing. See
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info.

am I starting it properly ?

Comment: The monitoring.yml docker-compose file is made to work with the app started locally (not in docker). You have to be aware that services started with docker-compose have their own "virtual networking" set up by docker and are not normally able to access any service running on localhost (although it's possible to access it when using docker "host" mode). This is why your prometheus cannot connect to your app as they are managed by different docker-compose files hence virtual networks.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the appropriate docker-compose configuration for your app + prometheus

- Create a new folder next to the one of your app: `mkdir ../docker && cd ../docker`
- Run `jhipster docker-compose`
- When prompted, input relative or absolute path to your app and select it in the list
- Choose the *Prometheus* option
- Finally you may run `docker-compose up -d`, make sure that all previously running containers were stopped